# How do I select the right RadioButton from a list of them in a DataFrom EditTemplate based on a SQL row value?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, ria, domainservices

I have a DataForm where I set the CurrentItem to an Entity returned from a LINQ RIA DataService. I am using Silverlight 4 with RIA services.

My "Current Item" is an Entity that a is row from SQL table. There's a column called "`RestartType`" on that table.

I have a DataForm where I set the DataForm.EditTemplate in the XAML.

I have three RadioButtons in my `EditTemplate`:

`<RadioButton Content="Restart 1" />
<RadioButton Content="Restart 2" />
<RadioButton Content="Restart 3" />`

How do I make it so IF the `RestartType` value is 0, then the `Restart 1` radio button gets selected but the other ones don't get selected, or if the `RestartType` value is 1, then `Restart 2` gets selected, and if it is 3 then `Restart 3` gets selected and other radio buttons get de-selected.

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the ContentLoaded event handler in my DataForm then I got the CurrentItem of the DataForm as my object. I used DataForm.FindNameInContent to get the EditTemplate controls and set the right RadioButton checked appropriately.